# ridge and lasso models in caret with lambda=0

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression, caret, glmnet

As far as I know, if I run a lasso model and a ridge model on the same data, and if i keep lambda=0, I'm getting the OLS. 
Then, how is it possible that I get different results?

```
rm(list=ls())
library(caret)

x1=rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
x2=rnorm(100, mean = 3, sd = 1)
y=x1+x2+rnorm(100, mean = 0.5, sd = 1)
dat=cbind(x1,x2,y)

control=trainControl(method = "cv",number=5)

set.seed(849)
ridge_caret<- train(dat[,1:2],dat[,3], method = "glmnet",
                trControl=control,preProc = c("center","scale"),
                tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0,
                                       lambda = 0))

set.seed(849)
lasso_caret<- train(dat[,1:2],dat[,3], method = "glmnet",
                trControl=control,preProc = c("center","scale"),
                tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1,
                                       lambda = 0))
```

For ridge, I'm getting:

```
RMSE      Rsquared   MAE      
1.031121  0.7159096  0.8503881
```

And for lasso,

```
RMSE      Rsquared   MAE      
1.031887  0.7157566  0.8485924
```

And of course, different coefficients:

```
> coef(ridge_caret$finalModel, ridge_caret$finalModel$lambdaOpt)
3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                1
(Intercept) 3.6183601
x1          0.9203728
x2          0.9718673
> coef(lasso_caret$finalModel, lasso_caret$finalModel$lambdaOpt)
3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                1
(Intercept) 3.6183601
x1          0.9657077
x2          1.0208237
```

¿Why are not they exactly the same?

Comment: You're not doing OLS.  If you want to do that, don't cross-validate.  With the cross-validation, you're doing a collection of OLS estimates on random subsets of the data.

Comment: Well, the fact is that I'm not really cross-validating to get my parameters, I'm just doing it to get an estimation of the test set error via RMSE... My parameters are fixed, and being lambda=0, I'm optimizing the same equations in both cases, so I expect the results to be the same. Caret returns the best cross-validated model, in this case the only one , trained on the whole set (lambda=0 so is OLS, right?), so I  think that both RMSE...and parameters should be the same.

Comment: This has nothing to do with cross-validation. Peter is right to question what is going on (+1). Given that the seed is fixed the bootstrapped/CV error should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that somewhat unfortunately you have hit a minor bug in `caret`'s implementation of the `glmnet` model. (Bug in the sense of "unintended behaviour") Your understanding about how GLMNet works is correct.

What you expect, *should happen* (i.e. setting $\lambda = 0$ should result to exactly the same estimate irrespective of $\alpha$ values) but it does not happen because actually the `glmnet` code in `caret` will "ignore" the `lambda` values so it can "hot-start" the LASSO optimisation. (It then manually treats the `lambda` from the grid as the "optimal $\lambda$" `lambdaOpt` to use it for the predictions that will give the RMSE/MAE estimates.)

If you want to use $\lambda = 0$, I would recommend you explicitly set it as an additional argument, like:

```
set.seed(849)
ridge_caret<- train(dat[,1:2],dat[,3], method = "glmnet",lambda= 0,
                    tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, lambda = 0))

set.seed(849)
lasso_caret<- train(dat[,1:2],dat[,3], method = "glmnet", lambda= 0,
                    tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1,  lambda = 0))
```

This would provide matching results that also match the output of simple `glmnet`.

```
lasso_raw <- glmnet( x= dat[,1:2], y = dat[,3], alpha = 1, lambda = 0)
ridge_raw <- glmnet( x= dat[,1:2], y = dat[,3], alpha = 0, lambda = 0)

all.equal(lasso_raw$beta, ridge_raw$beta) 
# TRUE
all.equal(ridge_raw$beta, ridge_caret$finalModel$beta)
# TRUE
all.equal(ridge_caret$finalModel$beta, lasso_caret$finalModel$beta)
# TRUE
```

As mentioned this seems to be unintentionally so you might wish to raise it as an issue in [`caret`'s github repo](https://github.com/topepo/caret/).

Comment: Side-note: If we want this to match the estimates from `lm` we need to note that `glmnet` sets `standardize = TRUE` by default. This needs to be set to `FALSE` (alongside `lambda =0` obviously) to match the output of `lm`.